# Cloudformation to terraform conversion of CodeDeployApplication

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am converting a Cloudformation template to terraform. I don't see materials online describing the terraform equivalent of CF structure.

**Cloudformation**

```
Resources:
  CodeDeployApplication:
    Type: 'AWS::CodeDeploy::Application'
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Join 
        - '-'
        - - !Ref EnvName
          - !Ref AppName
          - Application
      ComputePlatform: Lambda
```

I have converted as below. I am sure I have made a mistake in the 'name' part.Can you please help?

**Terraform**

```
resource "aws_codedeploy_app" "CodeDeployApplication" {
  compute_platform = "Lambda"
  name             = "${var.EnvName}/${var.AppName}/Application"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CFN code:

```
      ApplicationName: !Join 
        - '-'
        - - !Ref EnvName
          - !Ref AppName
          - Application
```

will translate to:

```
name             = "${var.EnvName}-${var.AppName}-Application"
```